# Floating point comparison in qmake

Tags: qt, qmake, comparison-operators

I'm trying to detect the version of a library in qmake and based on that set a preprocessor variable. I obtain the version number (a decimal number) using pkg-config and would like to compare it to a minimum version. I can use bc in shell script to do the floating point comparison but cannot get it to work using $$system in qmake.

```
LIBSTATGRAB_OLDAPI = $$system(echo "`pkg-config --modversion libstatgrab ` < 0.90 " | bc)
equals(LIBSTATGRAB_OLDAPI,"1") {
    message("Using old libstatgrab API")
    DEFINES += LIBSTATGRAB_OLD
}
```

The problem is that the shell command run by $$system seems to interpret the < character in the quotes as a readfile command and does not pipe the whole quoted block to bc.

```
sh: 1: cannot open 0.90: No such file
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bc` for this is not reliable in case if version number has more than one delimiter, e.g. `0.90.1`. My solution uses `sort`:

```
LIBSTATGRAB_OLDAPI = $$system(echo "`pkg-config --modversion libstatgrab` \\\\n 0.90" | sort -VbC; echo $?)
```

**Explanation**

`sort` is trying to check whether e.g. `0.95 \n 0.90` is unsorted, if so it exists with code `1`.

`\n` is escaped with four backslashes, this is a `qmake` requirement. `\n` is also surrounded with spaces for readability purpose, `sort -b` takes care of whitespace.

`sort -V` - designed for version sorting

`sort -b` - ignores whitespace

`sort -C` - silent check, we need only the exit code

`echo $?` - prints the exit code

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion!

It didn't work with the spaces around \\\\n and I changed it to "0.90\\\\n`pkg-config --modversion libstatgrab`" to check if version < 0.90 instead of 0.90 < version.